# Why am I getting segmentation fault and how do I solve this?

Tags: c

C program for bubble sort using a minimum of 4 functions.(input,output,compute,main)

- No global variables allowed.
- No `printf` or `scanf` in `compute`.
- No `printf` or `scanf` in `main`
- Input should not call `compute`.
- `compute` should not call `output`.

I haven't really understood pointers and functions.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void input(int* size, int* arr[])
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
        scanf("%d",size);

        printf("Enter the elements of the array\n");
        for(int i = 0;i < *size; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d", arr[i]);
        }
    }

    void swap(int *x,int *y)
    {
        int temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
    }

    void bubble_sort(int arr[100],int size)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < size - 1;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < size - 1 - i;j++)
            {
                if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    swap(&arr[j],&arr[j+1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void output(int size,int* arr)
    {
        printf("Sorted array\n");
        for(int i = 0;i < size;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",arr[i]);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {

        int* input_values[50];
        int size;
        input(&size, input_values);
        bubble_sort(size,*input_values);
        output(size, *input_values);
        return 0;
    }
```

No errors but showing  segmentation fault.How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you mean `int input_values[50];`? Otherwise, in `input()` you are using uninitialized pointers in `scanf("%d", arr[i]);`

Comment: Is this the actual code? Arguments to `bubble_sort` are wrong way around etc so it shouldn’t even compile

Comment: I get [lots of errors and warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/r_oqpS) when attempting to build that code. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly, please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. One that replicates the problem you have, and don't have other unrelated errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That might be because you're using a C++ compiler.

Comment: There's no `compute` function, is that supposed to be the name of `bubble_sort`?

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is here :

```
scanf(" %d", arr[i]);
```

You have to change this to :

```
scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);
```

This is the main problem, but there are a lot of others.
Also you have to change the order of parameters in

```
bubble_sort(size,*input_values);
```

to

```
bubble_sort(input_values,size);
```

and

```
output(size, *input_values);
```

to

```
output(size, input_values);
```

Also in order this to work at all i have changed the

```
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %d", &arr[i]);
```

Comment: Also `input_values` should be an `int` array, not `int*`.

Comment: Isn't the last change the same as the first one?

Comment: At first i suggested adding the "&" sign, because scanf needs pointer, then i added the space before "%d" but its optional i think

Comment: Yeah, it's not needed before `%d`, since that always skips whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is full of mistakes like the usage of `scanf` and the usage of pointers and arrays, the following is a workable version of you code see and compare:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int* size, int arr[])
{
    char chr;
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf( "%d%c", size, &chr );

    printf("Enter the elements of the array\n");
    for(int i = 0;i < *size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &chr);
    }
}

void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void bubble_sort(int* size,int arr[])
{
    for(int i = 0;i < *size - 1;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < *size - 1 - i;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                swap(&arr[j],&arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void output(int* size,int arr[])
{
    printf("Sorted array\n");
    for(int i = 0;i < *size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{

    int input_values[50];
    int s = 0;
    int* size = &s;
    input(size, input_values);
    bubble_sort(size,input_values);
    output(size, input_values);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use a character called chr ?

Comment: The `format` I used `"%d%c"` tells `scanf` to read digits and one character which is the newline character `\n` when you press `Enter`, so `chr` will contain the newline character, but it is not used while the code logic does not need it, so to say this is to tell `scanf` when to stop reading.

Comment: In the main function why should we declare an integer called s and initialize the the pointer size to address of s

Comment: That is exactly the reason because you need to initialize the pointer, otherwise it will be `NULL` pointer and will lead to `Segmentation fault` when assigned a value.